# Autoresizing iframes across domains where there is no access to frame content

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am setting up a website and i have an iframe with content loaded from external websites:

```
<iframe src="example.com"></iframe>
```

this leaves ugly double scroll bars on my page.

Have tried searching for solutions but ran into these issues:

1. cross doamin restrictions
2. i do NOT have access to 'example.com' as used in the illustration.

Is there any possible workaround for this problem?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Just set scrolling attribute as "no".

```
<iframe src="example.com" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

**UPDATE:**

If your content is just iframe, you can do it like this,

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
       body {overflow:hidden}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="http://example.com" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That will make the scrollbars disappear, but it won't do anything to address the problem of autoresizing.